# How to deal with .Net framework versions V4.0 vs V3.5 in Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net

I need to write a simple program in .net that runs easily on various other people's computers where those people do not have admin rights.

The problem is that Windows 8 no longer (fully) includes .Net 3.5 and earlier.

.Net 3.5 seemed to include the earlier versions, so targeting 2.0 would work with a 3.5 version.  But .net 4 no longer seems to include earlier versions the way that .net 3.5 did.

And yet every .net app seems to be bound to a .net version.  In combination that would mean that you need to build different versions of your .net application for each version of windows that a user might have.  That would be crazy, and Microsoft is generally very good about backwards compatibility.

Having the users install versions of .net is not an option -- they may not have admin rights.

**Solution**

This seems to work in *.exe.config

```
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/running-net-3-5-app-on-net-4-5-of-windows-8-and-server-2012

The default Windows 8 install (I just did one to a clean VM) seems to install V1.0, V1.1, V2.0 And V4.0 but only for 32 Bit.  Only V4.0 is installed for 64 bit.  My .exe did not specify bitness, so defaulted to 4.0, thus no .net.  An alternative solution might be to force 32 bit mode.

(I am guessing taht the Framework folder has the 32 bit versions, vs th Framework64 folder)

Comment: This may be a serious question, however you should be careful with your wording to not have the question flagged for closure as a rant in disguise.  The majority of your question body seems to be a complaint about the way the framework is designed, rather than a concrete request for assistance.

Comment: @Claies Thanks, edited.

Comment: Does this need to be a local desktop app? Depending on what the app is, I wonder if it may help if you do something different, like maybe a web based application.

Comment: @AaronS Yes, needs to be desktop.  And actually part of it is a .Net Excel addin using ExcelDNA.  If it were a web app I would use Java to keep my deployment options open.

Comment: generally, people ship .net applications written to target the latest framework available at the time of release, and bundle a silent automated or semi-automated installer of the .net framework runtime with their app installer.  The runtime installer will usually just run a check and drop out if the framework version is already installed.  Trying to write an app that targets what you think people already have installed is folly;  It's possible even in Win7 to not have **any** .net, even though it is bundled with the OS by default.

Comment: @Claies you would need admin rights to run that installer.  Plus I am wary of messing with people's configuration -- aggressive installers cause problems.  Especially in modern environments with "Application Virtualization" and other beasts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested this out myself, but I believe what you need is exactly the scenario for the [supportedRuntime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68(v=vs.110).aspx) configuration element.

You should then build your application targeting for example framework 3.5 (think it comes built in in Win7), and then add in the app.config file something like the following:

```
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually found this one https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/running-net-3-5-app-on-net-4-5-of-windows-8-and-server-2012

Answer (score 0):

You can include older assemblies in newer executables, so if you wanted to you could write the application in the oldest version of the framework that you want to support and then create executables for each framework version after that.

For example write everything in a 2.0 DLL and then create 2.0, 3.5 and 4.0 EXEs that just bootstrap the main DLL.

Your user would then just run the version that was installed on their OS.